# AspNetCore.Identity RemoveFromRoleAsync does not remove role from user

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I'm using ASP.NET Core Identity 2.0.2. When I call `UserManager.RemoveFromRoleAsync`, it does not remove the role from the user. It says:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager: Warning: User b651a459-5d6b-4239-88e6-facb33f11e87 is not in role Administrator.

Here's the code:

```
var userResult = await _userManager.RemoveFromRoleAsync(
    user,
    requestRole.ToReadableString());
```

I also tried to pass the role as an array in the `RemoveFromRolesAsync` function to no avail.

I don't see any other way to remove a role from a user.

---

**Update**

```
var roleResult = await _userManager
    .IsInRoleAsync(
        user,
        requestRole.ToReadableString());

var roleResult2 = await _userManager
    .IsInRoleAsync(
        user,
        "Administrator");

var roles = await _userManager
    .GetRolesAsync(user);

var userResult = await _userManager
    .RemoveFromRoleAsync(
        user,
        requestRole.ToReadableString());
```

roleResult and roleResult2 are both false.
roles contains "Administrator".
the user has the Role "Administrator" if I login with this user.
So the Authorize Attribute says the user has this role:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator", AuthenticationSchemes = "Bearer")]
```

---

Antoher test:

```
var roles = await _userManager
    .GetRolesAsync(user);

foreach (string role in roles)
{
    var roleTempResult = await _userManager
        .IsInRoleAsync(
            user,
            role);
}
```

The method IsInRoleAsync() returs false for all the roles returned from GetRolesAsync(user);
Whats going on there?

Comment: have you tried checking first if user is in role before trying to remove it.

Comment: For the error message, it said the User is not in `Administrator`. You may try to check the User whether it has `requestRole` role. Share the the records in database.

Answer (score 0):

Please

1. Look a correct name of role in "AspNetRoles" table
2. Look is user in role in "AspNetUserRoles" table
3. Specify a role name from "AspNetRoles" in RemoveFromRoleAsync

Comment: I use the enum for the role names, so it also uses that to add the role, this way I don't have tippos in the names. I also checked the database and the user has this role. in the UI the it shows me that the user has the Administrator role.

Answer (score 0):

You must use 'RoleName' instead of 'RoleId' in RemoveFromRoleAsync method.

```
await _userManager.RemoveFromRoleAsync(user,"Administrator");
```

Answer (score 0):

I hit this exact problem as well.

The problem was that the user I was passing in to all these functions was not a complete IdentityUser. It was an instance of IdentityUser and had the correct Id, UserName and Email, but other values like NormalizedEmail, NormalizedUserName and PasswordHash had been discarded when the user was retrieved in an earlier process.

Once I changed the retrieve process to not transform the users returned from GetUsersInRoleAsync, (I'd been populating a list with new IdentityUser instances based on the returned users and only setting the values I needed. Changing this to populate the list with the actual returned users fixed the problems), IsInRoleAsync and RemoveFromRoleAsync worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue when submitting all of the user roles defined by the application for removal using UserManager.RemoveFromRolesAsync(user, roles). It seems that if the user does not have membership in all of the submitted rows (i.e. one or more missing) then the call fails. I went with a work-around to ensure all of the target users roles are removed from the DB before adding one or more roles.

```
// Delete all current user roles
var userRoles = await _context.UserRoles.Where(_ => _.UserId == appUser.Id).ToListAsync();
_context.RemoveRange(userRoles);
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

// Add new roles
await _userManager.AddToRolesAsync(appUser, userProfile.Roles);
```